# Setting PDF page numbers/names when created by Export Map enabled with Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages

how to create PDF with Grid Number in  Data Driven Pages i tried to export PDF but it is export with page no like 1,2,3..... but i want to export with Grid Number is there any way to export like that could you please tell me.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Exporting_Data_Driven_Pages/00s900000038000000/[image]

Comment: You can add any feature-based information to your layout, provided it exists in the feature class that drives your data driven pages. It is available in the menu to the right in the DDP toolbar.

Comment: Is the text that you have circled coming from labelling that polygon or from Insert | Dynamic Text?  If you can provide more details like your Data Driven Pages Setup dialog, then it will be easier to advise.

Comment: But I doubt you can change the page numbering circeld to the left in your image, and is nothing that ArcMap can have any influence on. That is a property of the pdf document and/or the pdf viewer, and I have a hard time seeing any reasonable way to change how they are displayed.

Comment: @Martin I think you're right - perhaps it could be the subject of an ArcGIS Idea (if it is part of the document rather than put there by the viewer).

Comment: This is against the logic behind the page numbering in general however you can create bookmarks for each map grid. If you are good with Python, you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855907/adding-bookmarks-using-pypdf2

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, no, this is not possible using *page numbers*. Page numbers are a function of the document and are sequences of numbers, letters, or roman numerals. Word, Acrobat, and InDesign (which is highly customizable and specific to document creation) are three document softwares that I have on hand to check and allow only these formats; other software may differ. It *is* possible to incorporate them into a footer, combining them with other information - for example a custom footer that has:

`"date" - "sec no""page no"` appearing as `5/12/15 - A07`

In this case, as also suggested in comments, you need to place a dynamic text element wherever you want the 'page number' to be displayed and link it to the DDP index. The pdf still won't be navigable by going to page 'a6' or whatever - those would still be numeric. However you'd visually have your custom page number. Usually for this kind of document navigation you create a table of contents or index that matches the page numbers up to the DDP index of what is displayed on that page.